# Jquery UI datepicker inline getDate on select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How would I get the selected date from this, to pass via a POST?

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        var arrival = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
 });
</script>
```

And I get the calendar working like this:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="demo"></div>
```

Because is not an input, is a DIV I have this problem.
See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date picker fires an event when a date is selected.  You'd set the event handler to a function which then calls $.post inside it.

See [the date picker onSelect event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect).

If you would rather post the data in your arrival variable in your example, you'd just use jQuery's $.post function (or $.ajax if you want more control over the Ajax configuration).

Edit: here is how you'd pop up an alert box with the date:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { 
      onSelect: function(date, picker){ alert(date); }
    } );
} )
```

You initialize the datePicker with an object, and the object has a callback function at the 'onSelect' key.  This function is fired when a user selects a date.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer i did look at that page .. still i don't know how to get in an alert box the date selected when user selects a date could you help me please?

Comment: I added a code snippet to my answer that would pop up an alert.

Comment: missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] };  i tried to play with but because i have not much experience with javascript no valid result

Comment: Oops, I left off a right-paren.  Should work now... though I haven't tested it :)

Comment: $("#datepicker").datePicker is not a function
[Break On This Error] onSelect: function(date, picker){ alert(date); }

Comment: yeah, capital P.  I changed the answer again.